# Can any one explain Screenshot in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

// Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));
```

Can any tell me that

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE)
```

`getScreenShotAs` is the method in the `TakesScreenshot` Interface......

`(TakesScreenshot)driver`, What it refers to??? can you please explain little bit?

Comment: (TakesScreenshot)driver, Here you are defining the class, 'TakesScreenshot' just like an object to implement getScreenshotAs function. Walk through the class to observe the concept

Comment: getScreenshotAs() helps you to take screenshot

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`WebDriver`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) interface does not contain the `getScreenshotAs()` method, because it is possible to have a webdriver unable of taking screenshots - for example the in-memory drivers that don't render the page at all, like `HtmlUnitDriver`.

In order to have the method, the driver must implement the [`TakesScreenshot`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html) interface which makes it capable to ... well ... take screenshots.

Therefore, you must tell the program somehow that you want to take a screenshot and that you are absolutely sure you can do so. That's what the `(TakesScreenshot)driver` part is for. In Java, it's called [casting](https://www.google.com/search?q=Java+cast) and it literally translates to *"I know that this `driver` instance is able to take a screenshot, please cast it to `TakesScreenshot` type."*

If your cast succeeds, everything is fine and the `driver` object will be cast at run-time to an instance of `TakesScreenshot`. If your cast fails, however, you'll get a [`ClassCastExcepion`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) at run-time.

Some examples:

```
// We already know this is ok, because FirefoxDriver implements (IS-A) TakesScreenshot.
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
TakesScreenshot screenshottingDriver = (TakesScreenshot)driver;

// This will fail at run-time, because HtmlUnitDriver does not implement TakesScreenshot;
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
TakesScreenshot screenshottingDriver = (TakesScreenshot)driver;

// You can use the `instanceof` operator to check:
if (driver instanceof TakesScreenshot) {
    // we can be sure we can take screenshots, the cast will be safe
    ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(...);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you may read [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.java) it indicates that the driver can take a screenshot. It is necessary to do the casting because the *WebDriver* interface does not contain the *getScreenshotAs* method although it is implemented by most of the classes that implement that interface like *FirefoxDriver*.