# Why do we need to typecast Firefox driver to javascript executor?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, casting, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm a beginner in Java and Selenium and I came across `JavascriptExecutor` while working.

Wanted to know: though Remote webdriver and Firefox driver implement javascript executor, why can't I acess the method `executeScript()` directly and why should it be typecasted to get acessed?

Here is the program for javascript executor:

```
public class entertextwithoutsendkeys
{
    WebDriver driver;

    public entertextwithoutsendkeys()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void entertextpgm()
    {
        driver.get("https://www.gmail.com/");
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('Email').value='sh'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! When you post blocks of code, the best way to format it is to put 4 spaces at the start of each line. It makes it easier for everyone to read making it more likely you will get help.

Comment: Follow the below link it has a beautiful explanation:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877839/can-any-one-explain-screenshot-in-selenium/24311949#24311949

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `driver` variable (field, actually) is declared as of type `WebDriver`.

Since `FirefoxDriver` implements `WebDriver`, you can assign a `new FirefoxDriver()` to `driver` without problems.

Now you want to execute some JavaScript command. To do that, you must use the `executeScript()` method of the `JavascriptExecutor` interface.

`JavascriptExecutor` has nothing to do with the `WebDriver` interface (this one doesn't extend that one, for example), but `FirefoxDriver` happens to implement both.

So, even though your `driver` variable is seen as a `WebDriver` (due to its declaration), it actually holds as value an instance of `FirefoxDriver` - thus its value **is** a `JavascriptExecutor` as well (because `FirefoxDriver implements JavascriptExecutor`).

Still, you have to find a way of "looking at" that `driver` variable as if it were a `JavascriptExecutor`, so you can execute this interface's methods (like `executeScript()`). **The way to do this**, this "looking at", **is casting**, just as you did.

You wouldn't have to do any cast if you declared `driver` as of type `FirefixDriver`. Try it yourself.